# Vaadin Container.Filter using variable number of criterias

Tags: vaadin

Just implemented the new Container.Filter using this code:

```
Filter f  = 
new Or(new SimpleStringFilter(Columns.SEARCH.id(), "rpm-diastolic", true, false),  
new Or(new SimpleStringFilter(Columns.SEARCH.id(), "rpm-systolic", true, false)),
new Or(new SimpleStringFilter(Columns.SEARCH.id(), "rpm-weight", true, false))) ;
container.addContainerFilter(f);
```

and works fine.

Now I would like to use the following in order to build as many criterias I would need by building dynamically the filter:

```
List<String> filters;
for(String filter : filters) {
    Filter f  = new Or(new SimpleStringFilter(Columns.SEARCH.id(), filter, true, false) );
    container.addContainerFilter(f);
}
```

How can I do this for this code doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

I was able to do this by simply passing an array to the Or constructor this way:

```
Filter[] filtersToAdd = new Filter[filters.size()];
for(String filterString : filters) {
filtersToAdd[i++] = 
    new Or(new SimpleStringFilter(Columns.SEARCH.id(), filterString, true, false));
}
Filter f = new Or(filtersToAdd);
container.addContainerFilter(f);
```

Comment: I want to apply multiple Filter on same column. Is it valid or not? I tried, its only work when 1 filter is applied. I am trying to use multiple filter with `And (Container.Filter... filters)`. I am not getting any errors, but it seems when there are more filters , container is not getting filtered.

Comment: My code is just like the same, difference is I am using `And` instead of `Or` and `Compare.Equal` instead of `SimpleStringFilter`. I want to apply Filters for multiple values but on a same column. [Note: Between is not useful in my case because There isn't any range in what I am comparing.] So, I am making multiple Filters for same column but with different values in each filter. [Note: I am also wrapping this each filter with `Not` filter, as I am collecting the values which I don't want to display. Because those are less in compare what I want to display. ]

Comment: You will need to use the Or in this case... otherwise you will get 0 returned objects. if your column contains (cat, mouse, dog) and you use And filters, your column will never be equal to "dog" AND "mouse" at the same time...

Comment: ya. I got this problem later. So now I am adding each filter ,with different column value, separately, with loop. I mean I am just simply creating filter in loop and adding it to Filterable Container.   But how can I achieve this with `Or` ? I want to hide all these specific values. It will also be helpful if you can tell about the which code is efficient and how. Thanxx.