# Vaadin Grid - joining filters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, grid, vaadin, vaadin7

i have problem with filters in vaadin.
I know how to create filter for one column, and another filter in another TextField for second column, but i dont know how to make one filter, or maybe two filters which ll be assign to one TextField. 
So I want to make one TextField where i can find/ filter data from more than one column.

Now I have this:

```
filter = new SimpleStringFilter(columnId, event.getText(), true, true);
f.addContainerFilter(filter);
```

and

```
TextField filter = getColumnFilter("column1", grid);

filteringHeader.getCell("column1").setComponent(filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understood your question properly. If your intention is to implement multiple filters on a container then you can refer to this SO page [Multiple filters for container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524495/vaadin-container-filter-using-variable-number-of-criterias)

Comment: You can concat filters with either Or(Filters ...) or And(Filters ...).